# I am authorized developer of another app but I can`t find this app

Tags: facebook

I was added as authorized developer of my employer's facebook account. At least he said so. But I can't find any notes about it in my FB dashboard or apps. What am I supposed to do to manage his FB application? Where can I see it?

Comment: They change their rules every day... have you tried to 'like' the app first?

Comment: Hi. Yes I Liked it before they told me that I am authorized. Thank you Ps I liked the page not the app, I can't see the app.

Comment: Im reading again your question, how can he add you to his account? He can add you as an administrator to the app he created, than you will get a request that you need to accept (at least it was like that).

Comment: Thank you for reply, I wrote all I know. They told that I need to like a FB page and after that they added me as authorized developer. But I`m stuck, how to see /edit this app if it exists? Or create an app on his facebook account. I feel frustrated

Comment: You should login as a FB developer and there should be an invitation.

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean 'login as developer'? Thanks

Comment: You need to login [here](https://developers.facebook.com/).

Comment: Done - no changes. Where I should see that I am in other owner`s FB space? Thank you

Comment: I do not think you can be 'in other space', but you should see an invitation on a little globe. Also try to 'unlike' the page, found that solution [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151751407029455)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to see the app listed here:  https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Then to manage it, you can click on the icon which brings you to the application's dashboard/settings page (or analytics if he gave you only analytics role).

If you don't see the app in the list of apps, check your requests to see if you have the app waiting to be accepted.  To do that, you can click on your profile picture and click on 'requests' or go here:  https://developers.facebook.com/requests/

If the app is not there waiting to be accepted, then you will have to ask an admin to (re)invite you from the roles page.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, you`re right! They re-invited me and I've got an invitation email and message in FB. But the only issue is how to add new FB application to their FB, not mine? Thank you

Comment: The best way to add a new FB application for someone else is to create an FB application, make them an admin, then once they accept it (and see them under app settings > roles > administrators), highlight your name/picture under app settings > roles and remove yourself as admin.